# How to pass an HTTP request as a parameter of a python function?

Tags: python, django

I'm calling a python function and passing an HTTP request as a parameter but it's not working. I created the function in a View and called it in another, but the parameter fails.

Here's the function I'm calling

```
def load_colmeias(request):
    apiario = request.GET.get('apiario')
    if apiario != "":
        colmeias = Colmeia.objects.filter(apiario=apiario)
        return render(request, 'colmeias_choices.html', {'colmeias': colmeias})
    else:
        return render(request, 'colmeias_choices.html')
```

Here I call her

```
load_colmeias(request)
```

But the following error occurs

```
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

I already imported the "urlib" and "requests" libraries but it always gives the same error:

```
AttributeError: module has no attribute 'GET'
```

Can someone help me ?? I'm new to Python/Django and I'm still learning how to do things

Comment: Seems like `request` must be a HTTPRequest object

Comment: To pass the request you first need to _have_ the request. Apparently you don't have a `request` in the scope where you call the function (of which you show little code to us)... Please visit the [help] and have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `requests` installed:

```
import requests
r=requests.get("https://automatetheboringstuff.com/files/rj.txt")
print(len(r.text))
```

Now, check:

- In `load_colmeias(request)`, make sure the parameter is actually `request` and not `requests` throughout.
- Your filename is not `requests.py`; otherwise you would be importing your own file.

Answer (score 0):

**request** and **requests** are two different things, one without 's' is a parameter and with 's' is a method. to use **requests** you have to import **requests library** this is a third party library to fetch data from an API.

if you want to call this function you have to make a request through an API. create an API for this function and then make a request.

your views.py file:

```
def load_colmeias(request):
    apiario = request.GET.get('apiario')
    if apiario != "":
        colmeias = Colmeia.objects.filter(apiario=apiario)
        return render(request, 'colmeias_choices.html', {'colmeias': colmeias})
    else:
        return render(request, 'colmeias_choices.html')
```

Your urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

path('load_colmeias', views.load_colmeias)
]
```

Now your API is:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/load_colmeias?apiario=1234

make sure you have used the correct port in the api and have started the server before making the request and pass the correct value of apiario.

There is another way to call this function by using **requests library**:

```
import requests

res = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/load_colmeias?apiario=1234')
print(res.text)
```

you can use this in any file and call your function like this using this library again the server must be running and pass the correct value of apiario.
Well if you are passing a request parameter then you have to make the request. You can't call it the way you have shown.

Comment: I understand what you said... The point is that this request is made in javascript and captured by the parameter "request" in the function "load_colmeias". But I want to reuse this code to call in other views, but it doesn't work... It only works if I create a function in each view with the same code... In short: when I create the function and pass the "request" it works, but when I call this same function passing the "request" then it gives the aforementioned errors.

Comment: ok, what I can see is that when you are calling the same function again, you are calling it with 'request' as parameter, but u never call a function using the parameter again, you have to use the value to call it. you give the parameter while defining the function. if you are using request as value, which is never defined by you, that's why it is showing you this error: NameError: name 'request' is not defined, first you have to define the value of request and then use it to call the function.

Comment: I hope the following easiest function would clear your concept to call the function: def add(num1, num2):
    result = num1 + num2
    return result
    
print(add(1, 3)) ===> This is how you call the function using the values, and not using the parameter, num1 and num2 again.

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED THE PROBLEM !! Basically, I just created a function that calls another function and passed the same argument to both... As can be seen below:

```
def load_colmeias(request):
    return carregar_colmeia(request)
```

I don't know if it's recommended, but it solved my problem of having to rewrite the same code in multiple views.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand how this worked. Will you be able to clarify?